# TCDL tags are not getting converted in smartTarget tags

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

After addinng TCDL region on page template, and after publishing tags loosk like below

```
            <tcdl:promotions region='PromoBox' maxItems='1'> 
                <tcdl:itemTemplate> 
                    <tcdl:promotionalItems> 
                        <tcdl:itemTemplate> 
                                <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:80-4632-64" ComponentURI="##componentUri##" TemplateURI="##templateUri##"/> 
                        </tcdl:itemTemplate> 
                    </tcdl:promotionalItems> 
                </tcdl:itemTemplate> 
                <tcdl:fallbackContent> 


                </tcdl:fallbackContent> 
            </tcdl:promotions> 

        </tcdl:query> 
        </tcdl:region>
```

but all tcdl tags must be converted into smartarget as below.

```
        <smarttarget:Query PageId="tcm:55-5995-64" Publication="tcm:0-55-1" runat="server"> 

            <smarttarget:Promotions MaxItems="1" Region="PromoBox" runat="server"> 
                <ItemTemplate> 
                    <smarttarget:PromotionalItems runat="server"> 
                        <ItemTemplate> 
                                <tridion:ComponentPresentation runat="server" PageURI="tcm:55-5995-64" ComponentURI="<%# Eval(&quot;ComponentUri&quot;) %>" TemplateURI="<%# Eval(&quot;TemplateUri&quot;) %>"/> 
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                    </smarttarget:PromotionalItems> 
                </ItemTemplate> 
                <FallbackContent> 


                </FallbackContent> 
            </smarttarget:Promotions> 

        </smarttarget:Query> 
           <!-- End Promo -->
```

Any Idea why these are not getting converted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SmartTarget tcdl tags are transformed by the Tridion Deployer. The SmartTarget module needs to be added to the cd_deployer_conf.xml.

add the following to the `<Processors>` element

```
<Processor Action="Deploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction">     
   <Module Type="SmartTargetDeploy" Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperDeployerModule">        
     <Transformer Class="com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer"/>    
   </Module>  
</Processor>   
<Processor Action="Undeploy" Class="com.tridion.deployer.Processor" Phase="post-transaction">      
  <Module Type="SmartTargetUndeploy" Class="com.tridion.smarttarget.deployer.FredhopperUndeployModule"/>    
</Processor>
```

and add the following `TagBundle` to the `<TCDLEngine>` element:

```
<TagBundle Resource="com/tridion/smarttarget/tcdl/tagbundle.xml"/>
```

If the deployer is configured correctly, verify if the PublicationTarget language is set to ASP.NET or JSP

Comment: Cool! I resolved already. I had already implemented same on multiple projects but this time, I was verifying my changes in separate deployer but  publishing was going through different deployed.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, can you accept it? It will help other people with the same issue